# Django Virtualenv production tradeoffs

Tags: django, virtualenv

Are there any tradeoffs (memory, performance etc) while deploying Django in production with virtualenv?

I like how it's all sandboxed and clean but can't seem to find any performance info.

Any direction would be nice.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no natural difference between env managed by Virtualenv and those not using it: just different filesystem directories and Python paths.  Furthermore, Virtualenv saves our Dev's time by providing sandbox-env you mentioned, allowing flexible configuration of envs and switching between them on single node, exempting requirement of sudo... which, IMO, is big 'performance' gain.

Answer (score 1):

None, I think. I always use virtualenv. Regardless of packages' location on disk, they all have to be loaded in memory for Django's process. The hard part is rebuilding the virtualenv when you need to recompile python, but i don't see any performance issues at all.